# Dynamically get the values from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I want to add a new column to my data frame based on values from a transition matrix.

I tried this solution [[R extract values from matrix given dataframe of x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949735/r-extract-values-from-matrix-given-dataframe-of-x-and-y]) but it seems to work for numbers as indexes, and I have character names for my rows and columns.

For example:

```
r
x<- 
cbind(c(0.3,0.35,0.35,0),c(0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2)
,c(0,0.6,0.1,0.3),c(0.5,0.25,0.25,0))
colnames(x) <- c("A","B","C","D")
rownames(x) <- c("A","B","C","D")

y<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
,c("A","A","B","A","B","A"),c("D","C","C","D","D","D")))
colnames(y) <- c("id","e1","e2")

index_df = y%>% select(e1,e2)
colnames(index_df)<-c('rows','cols')

y[as.matrix(index_df)]
```

I get this error

> Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds

I want to add a column names l1 to y data frame with the values from the matrix

```
   id e1 e2 l1  
1  1  A  D  0.50  
2  2  A  C  0.0  
3  3  B  C  0.2  
4  4  A  D  0.50  
5  5  B  D  0.25  
6  6  A  D  0.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the right dataset to extract the values.  Here, 'y' doesn't have the rows or columns matching.  It is 'x'

```
y$l1 <- x[as.matrix(index_df)]
y$l1
#[1] 0.50 0.00 0.60 0.50 0.25 0.50
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction! It was ok for the example I builded wrong, but I'm still having problems on the real data. I will update the post with real data.

Comment: @OscarBenitez  sure, will check it out

Comment: Found the issue!
The 'e1' and 'e2' variables of the dataframe 'y' did not have the same strings as the row and column names of the matrix. Just replacing an elusive underscore did the job